# persisting data on a page between url calls

Tags: grails

Sure this is a very common requirement, but not able to find any relevant documentation on this.

In my application I have a chartPage.gsp which has many textfields and buttons, I use them to display charts, search etc. When I click one of the buttons(like drillchart) it takes me to another page in the app - results.gsp (in the same window). This internally is a jquery.ajax() call which I make to invoke the URL.

I need to have a back button on the results page which will take me back to the chartPage.gsp with all the values previously loaded before the call, like the browser back button.

Right now the browser back button is not saving the state of the calling page. How do I save the state with all the data in the calling page?

Update: Right now I am trying the history.back()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Controllers/session.html

Comment: So in short do I have to add all textfields I change on the chartPage to the session and use them from the resultsPage as parameters when I invoke the url for back button?

Comment: You do not need to pass parameters. Just get the default values in your chartPage from the session.

Comment: So I guess I would need to reset the values in the session when making a fresh call to chartPage..(differentiate the call from back button and a direct call from a tab click..)